# For $0<a<b$ and $n>0$, show that $\left|\int_{a}^b \frac{\cos x}{x^n}\,dx\right|\leq \frac{2}{a^n}.$

Tags: real-analysis, integral-inequality

**For $0<a<b$ and $n>0$, show that $\left|\int_{a}^b \frac{\cos x}{x^n}\,dx\right|\leq \frac{2}{a^n}.$**

I did some estimate, but it got much bigger bound:
$$
\left|\int_{a}^b \frac{\cos x}{x^n}\,dx\right| \leq \int_{a}^b\left|\cos x\right|\frac{1}{x^n}dx\leq \int_{a}^b \left|\cos x\right|\frac{1}{a^n}dx\leq(b-a) \frac{1}{a^n}.
$$
Is there any suggestion how to get the bound $2/a^n?$ Thanks.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz might be helpful here, but it introduces at least one annoyance. It may be a place to start, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Mean-Value theorem for integrals, there is $\xi\in(a,b)$ such that
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\left|\int_{a}^b \frac{\cos x}{x^n}dx\right|=\left|\frac{1}{\xi^n}\int_{a}^b \cos x dx\right|=\frac{1}{\xi^n}|\sin b-\sin a|\\
&\le& \frac{2}{\xi^n}\le\frac{2}{a^n}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I think we can get the form $\frac{\cos \xi}{\xi^n} (b-a)$ by MVT for integrals. but how can you get the first equality?

Comment: @Pei-LunTseng, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem.

Comment: Yes! you are right. I forgot this form. Thanks!